# Python Value Error: Could not be broadcast together with shapes

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, linear-algebra

```
w = scipy.linalg.inv(X.transpose() * X)* X.transpose() * y;
```

When I execute the following inside one of my functions.. I get the following error. I'm kind of new to Python and would appreciate any help. Thank you.

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (64,242) (242,64)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`*` isn't matrix multiplication*. For matrix multiplication, you should use `numpy.dot` or the `dot` method of array objects.

```
w = scipy.linalg.inv(X.T.dot(X)).dot(X.T).dot(y)
```

*unless you're using the specific class where it is. Don't use that class; it'll produce bigger headaches than you already have.